Who was the original Dr. Feelgood, and what did he practice?
I am interested in the emergence and evolution of the slang term “Doctor Feelgood.”
J.L. Lighter, The Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang (1994) has this entry for the term:

Doctor Feelgood n. an unscrupulous physician who prescribes mood-altering drugs, esp. amphetamines. on demand. [Earliest cited occurrence:] {1967 J. Kramer Instant Replay 40: Ever since then we’ve called him “Doctor Feelgood.”}

In Instant Replay, Jerry Kramer’s diary of his 1967 season as a lineman for the Green Bay Packers, however, the “Doctor Feelgood” is Willie Davis, the Packers’ defensive team captain. Here is the fuller context of the quote cited in Lighter:

Willie’s the best storyteller on the team; he can imitate almost anyone. For years he’s had the nickname of “Doctor,” and once a few of us asked him how he got the name. “Women gave it to me in my youth,” said Willie. They all called me ‘Doctor’ because I made them feel so good.” Ever since then, we’ve called him “Dr. Feelgood.”

Meanwhile, Clarence Major, Juba to Jive: A Dictionary of African-American Slang (1994) has this entry for the term:

Dr. Feelgood. (1960a–1970s) a good feeling; name of a song by Aretha Franklin; to feel beautiful and fulfilled; to feel blessed.

Aretha Franklin released her song “Dr. Feelgood” in 1967. The lyrics explaining the title run as follows:

Don't send me no doctor / Filling me up with all of those pills / I got me a man named Doctor Feelgood / And oh, yeah, that man takes care of all of my pains and my ills / His name is
Doctor Feelgood in the morning / And taking care of business / Is really this man's gain / And after one visit to Doctor Feelgood / You'll understand why Feelgood is his name / Oh, yeah, oh good God almighty / The man sure makes me feel real good

Robert Hendrickson, The Facts on File Encyclopedia of Word and Phrase Origins, fourth edition (2008) has this entry:

Doctor Feelgood. Any doctor who makes a specialty of writing prescriptions for amphetamines and other mind-altering drugs meant to induce euphoria in a patient. The name’s earliest recorded use is 1967. It was popularized by the Aretha Franklin song of that title.

My questions are as follows:

1. What is the first published occurrence of “Doctor Feelgood”?
2. When did it appear in print?
3. What did the term then refer to?
4. When did the transition in meaning of “Dr. Feelgood” to “unscrupulous medication-dispensing doctor” occur?

In a few minutes, I will post an answer describing the (incomplete) results of my research into this question.

In Google Books search results, the earliest clearly relevant match for “Doctor Feelgood” appears in “Reviews of New Singles,” in Billboard Music Week (January 20, 1962):

DR FEEL GOOD AND THE INTERNS Doctor Feel Good—OKEH 7144—Over a pulsating background, Dr. Feel Good turns in a bright performance of a catchy novelty that swings. The good doctor shouts. it with excitement, while the boys back him closely. Watch this one for pop and r.&b. (Cigma, BMI) (2:18)

The performer who calls himself “Doctor Feelgood” here is Willie Lee Perryman, known earlier in his career as “Piano Red.” The lyrics to this song run as follows:

Hey, all of you women / Now don’t come around / Unless you weigh / Around four hundred pounds / I’m from way down home / And I don’t dig chawing bone / You got to be / All right with me/ Because the doctor / Is really hard to please / Now you talk about women / I love ’em all / I love ’em big / And then I love ’em tall / But if you don’t weigh / What I want, baby / Don’t come around at all / Well, you got to be / All right with me / Because the doctor / Is really hard to please / ... / Well, they call me the doctor / In my neighborhood / But my baby, she calls me  / Oh, Doctor Feelgood / Oh yeah, but feels good / Have you never been good / Well, you talk about women / That’s all I pray / I believe, I believe / They gonna take me to my grave / Good good good good good good / So good ...

Although Perryman took on the name “Doctor Feelgood,” authorship of the song (both words and music) is credited to his guitarist, Curtis Smith in Catalog of Copyright Entries, Third Series, Volume 15, Part 5, Number 2 (1962). In an interview recorded on August 26, 1962 by Chris Strachwitz of Arhoolie Records, Perryman gives this very brief account of the name:

Chris Strachwitz:  I noticed that, for Victor, you recorded quite a bit and then you came back, and now recently on Okeh. When did you start this Dr. Feelgood thing?
Piano Red:  Well, that’s when we started. I got a radio show that’s called Dr. Feelgood Show, and we wrote that from the show, Dr. Feelgood Show.

Paul Hornung, another Green Bay Packer, seems to connect this song to Willie Davis’s nickname in a book published three years before Instant Replay came out. From Paul Hornung, Football and the Single Man (1965):

Willie Davis we call Dr. Feelgood. There was a song about Dr. Feelgood one time and Willie's personality fits that piece. He always feels good, you know. He's got a great gift of gab. He's very funny and everyone loves to hear him tell a story. He can tell a story about walking into a grocery store and have you in stitches. And down on the field , he's just a tremendous pass rusher.

Interestingly, Hornung’s sense of the expression is that it fits Davis because Davis feels good all the time.
Although the explicit term “Doctor Feelgood” may have originated with him, Perryman clearly owes a substantial debt to Doc Pomus and his 1950 song “Send for the Doctor”:

Well they call me Doc, I can make you feel so good / Well they call me Doc, I can make you feel so good / Do more for you than any man in this neighborhood / If you ever feel stiff around your back / Send for me and you'll hear a crack / Call me Doc, make you feel so good / Do more for you than any man in this neighborhood / Freezing cold and you feel half alive / Run your fever to a hundred and five / Send for the doctor, make you feel so good / More for you than any man in this neighborhood / You get those shivers around your spine / Run your fever to a hundred and nine / Send for the doctor, make you feel so good / Do more for you than any man in this neighborhood / Cure every ache and ease every pain / My kinda cure gonna drive you insane / Send for the doctor any time you feel the flu / 'Cause old Doc Pomus is just the man for you

It thus appears that “Doctor Feelgood” originated as a reference to a “doctor of love” who used his natural talents to alter the mood and improve the health of his figurative patients.
With regard to when “Dr. Feelgood” began to be associated with providers of mood-altering drugs, the earliest definite instance I could find is in a review of Peter De Lissovoy, Feelgood: A Trip in Time and Out (1970), “The Rage of Being Young and Lost,” in Life Magazine (September 4, 1970):

He meets a herb-healer Negro Thoreau named Dr. Feelgood. Feelgood carries a pouch of the finest grass De Lissovoy has ever blown. He shares it with De Lissovoy and his pal Yellow as they fish for "sunnies" or sit in a tree and watch the river turn magic.

In De Lissovoy’s novel itself, the character "Feelgood” is mentioned seven times as “Doctor [or Dr.] Feelgood.” In one scene he extols the virtues of cannabis:

Blues of preacher Joe Tex, Betty Everett, Otis Redding jumped out of the small box at yellow’s side. It was a beautiful picnic. Doctor Feelgood got out his pipe after lunch, and we passed it.
"If you high, you feel a volume a the air, that curvin on your shoulders an the topside a trees, but it don weigh on ya, it connect ya. It don matter how you die, if you in your figure."

Explicit use of “Dr. Feelgood” in connection with what amount to credentialed drug pushers appears in an influential article that was subsequently inserted, in full, into the Congressional Record of March 2, 1971. From Susan Wood, “Dr. Feelgood, Are You Sure It’s All Right?” in New York Magazine (February 8, 1971):

Regardless of which Dr. Feelgood has the most prominence at the moment—fashions change—each patient, aglow with the incredible zap of his latest shot, is sure his doctor alone is the real Dr. Feelgood. But each Dr. Feelgood has at least two things in common with the next—a persuasive personality and a lucrative practice.

Ralph Slovenko, Psychiatry and Law (1973) asserts that one doctor operating in this demimonde of jet-setting drug users was Max Jacobson:

As revealed by an investigation by the New York Times, a general practitioner in New York, Dr. Max Jacobson (called Dr. Feelgood), over a period of years was injecting a concoction containing amphetamine into the veins of the country’s most celebrated people, including author Truman Capote, movie director Cecil B. DeMille, singer Eddie Fisher, President and Mrs. Jack Kennedy , playwright Alan Jay Lerner, Rep . Claude Pepper, movie director Otto Preminger, fashion designer Emilio Pucci, actor Anthony Quinn, and playwright Tennessee Williams.

However, the New York Times article that Slovenko seems to be referring to—Noyce Rensberger, “Amphetamines Used by Physician to Lift Moods of Famous Patients” (December 4, 1972) doesn’t refer to him as “Dr. Feelgood,” and it isn’t clear when that term was first attached to Dr. Jacobson. Richard Lertzman & William Birnes, Dr. Feelgood: The Shocking Story of the Doctor Who May Have Changed History by Treating and Drugging Prominent Figures Including President Kennedy, Marilyn Monroe, and Elvis Presley (2013) asserts that the Secret Service had given Jacobson the code name “Dr Feelgood” during the Kennedy administration:

Code-named “Dr. Feelgood” by the Secret Service Detail guarding the president, Max Jacobson was an omnipresent figure among those surrounding President Kennedy and First Lady Jacqueline during the two-and-a-half years they occupied the White House.

In another book, UFO Hunters Book Two: The Official Companion to the Hit Television Series, Birnes identifies the source of the earlier claim that the Secret Service had code-named Jacobson “Dr. Feelgood” as “retired [Secret Service] agent Paul Landis.” If this claim is true, it would move this usage to the early 1960s.
However, I have not found any earlier published report that the Secret Service gave Jacobson this code name during the Kennedy administration. Lertzman & Birnes also asserts without substantiation that Aretha Franklin’s song “Doctor Feelgood” is about Jacobson—another claim not asserted in any Google Books source prior to theirs. In fact, Franklin explicitly contrasts her “Dr. Feelgood” with the kind of doctor she doesn’t want to see: “Don’t send me to no doctor / Filling me up with all of those pills.”
A perhaps unrelated instance of “Dr. Feelgood” pops up unexpectedly in a brief item in a 1953 issue of House Beautiful magazine (month not confirmed, but volume 95 extends across parts of the 1952 and 1953 calendar years):

PILL-JOY. The doctor’s satchel is made of black ceramic with hand-painted flowers, and the cheerful name of the Doc, printed across the front is Dr. U. Will Feelgood. Open it up, and you have a 3-sectioned holder for pills. Keep one in the dining room, another on your bed table, and you'll take your medicine with a smile. $2.75 ppd. Ranch House, Goleta, California.

Even earlier is a character named “Dr. Feelgood” (originally introduced as “Dr. Payne”)  who is a continuous character from September 29 to November 18 in the daily comic strip “Etta Kett.” As the strip published in the Ypsilanti [Michigan] Daily Press on October 19, 1944, indicates, the character is a “psycho-analyst”—but he is never shown prescribing any medicine and rarely even has a patient. It seems unlikely that this Dr. Feelgood had any influence on the emergence of the slang term of later years.
Conclusions
Although the reference works cited in my original question traced published instances of “Dr Feelgood” only as far back as 1967, earlier instances of the name occur in a comic strip from 1944, in an advertisement for a ceramic pillbox from 1953, in a popular song from 1962, and in a football memoir from 1964.
The strongest line of connection I see in my research results involves blues and r&b songs, progressing from Doc Pomus’s “Send for the Doctor” in 1950 (with its repeated line “make you feel so good”) to Piano Red’s “Doctor Feel-Good” in 1962 to Aretha Franklin’s ‘Dr Feelgood” in 1967. To my eye and ear, none of these songs is drug-related, except in the Brian Ferry sense that love is a drug.
Clarence Majors’ note that in the U.S. Black community of the 1960s “Dr. Feelgood” became a metaphor for a sense of bliss finds some support in this excerpt from a poem by Nikki Giovanni, called “for 2 james--ballantine and snow,”  written in August 1969 and published in Black World (September 1970):

your pediatrician was dr. doolittle / only knew how to make you / breathe / now you got dr. feelgood
he opened the womb / and you set up a long / Black moan

The sense of “Dr. Feelgood” as a promiscuous dispenser of various prescription drugs might have originated in the early 1960s (if you are inclined to believe the decades-after-the-fact claim that the U.S. Secret Service assigned the code name “Dr Feelgood” to a doctor who supplied President Kennedy with various quickie prescriptions and drug injections during the period of 1961–1963). I am skeptical of this claim, however, in the absence of pre-1971 instances of this usage in print. The earliest contemporaneous use of the term in the “free-and-easy illicit drug distributor” sense seems to be from a magazine article published in early 1971. A crossover instance of sorts occurs in a 1970 novel in which the protagonist hangs out and gets high with a non-physician known as “Dr. Feelgood.”
Both of the instances from 1967 that I noted earlier—Aretha Franklin’s song and Jerry Kramer’s football memoir—betray no awareness of the “doctor gone wild” sense of the term. I was struck by the fact that Kramer’s book presents the team’s “Dr. Feelgood” as a teammate who is a funny, articulate ladies’ man; meanwhile, the team’s trainer seems to dispense No. 3 Emperin-codeine painkillers in pill form to players more or less on demand—and no one applies the name to him.
My current hypothesis is that “Dr Feelgood” began to be applied to malpracticing doctors sometime after 1967, probably playing on the popularity Franklin’s song. It was definitely in use in that sense by early 1971. I will gladly revise my proposed timeline backward if anyone can point to contemporaneous print references to a prescription-writing “Dr Feelgood” from the 1960s or earlier.

Along the lines of “free-and-easy illicit drug distributor,” from 1968: ‘Dr. Feelgood’ Presides: They lit little fires, babbled politics and frenzy and smoked synthetic pot. “It’s legal for 14 more days,” said a boy who was playing “Dr. Feelgood” and passing the joints out free. —“Trace of Tear Gas in Perfume” by Nicholas Von Hoffman, The Washington Post, 29 Aug 1968.

@TinfoilHat: That's an excellent find—thank you! I can't judge whether the amateur purveyors of illegal substances were a transition from "Dr. Feelgood" as a "love doctor" to "Dr Feelgood" as "medical-degreed supplier to a clientele of junkies" or a parallel development. But it is great to see an additional instance of it—especially one that appeared before the one I found.
